# Shutting down a website using HTaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

OK, it's very simple but it does not work. I have a wiki site where the root contains an index.php file and the subdirectories contains the content of the wiki (I use PMwiki, so no database is required)

I want to temporarity shutdown the website and make it unaccessible by using an nice HTML page to display the shutdown message. I could rename the index.php file, but the rest of the files in the subfolder will remain accessible.

The first thing that worked but which is not elegant is restricting the whole site with a password in the htaccess using "Require valid-user" and all it's other command. The problem is that I cannot display a nice shutdown message as an HTML file.

Else I tried renaming the index.php file to something else like site.php. Creating a index.html file as a message and using a script like this:

```
Order Deny, allow
Deny from all

<File "index.html">
   Allow from all
</File>
```

In that case, the index.html file is accessible, but it must be manually typed in the URL, it will not use this file by default. I tried adding DirectoryIndex directive like this

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

But it still does not work.

So first is there a way to make the user only see 1 page in particular and block everything else.

Second, doing so makes the site unaccessible to me. So is there a way to passords restrict the whole directory structure except for a specific index.html file. So that I could type url/site.php and be able to enter my website using an htaccess password.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Just this rule in root .htaccess should be able to handle this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !^shutdown\.html$ shutdown.html [L,NC]
```

Now you can keep custom HTML content in `/shutdown.html`. Keep in mind you need to use inline css/js since it will also rewrite css/js requests to `/shutdown.html` file.

Comment: Else I tried redirecting on a different page on a failure or clicking cancel on the authentification screen with `ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/shutdown.html\"></html>"` but I get an infinite loop of authentication screen.

Comment: You don't need to have ErrorDocument 401 there, just one rule as I suggested should be enough.